# codeigniter undefined offset error

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart

I'm currently learning cart system with CI and got some problems

```
A PHP Error was encountered 
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 2
Filename: models/main_model.php
Line Number: 241
```

here's the code:

**Controller:**

```
function update_cart(){
    $this->main_model->validate_update_cart();
    redirect('cart');
}
```

**Model:**

```
function validate_update_cart(){

    // Get the total number of items in cart
    $total = $this->cart->total_items();

    // Retrieve the posted information
    $item = $this->input->post('rowid');
    $qty = $this->input->post('qty');

    // Cycle true all items and update them
    for($i=0;$i < $total;$i++)
    {
        // Create an array with the products rowid's and quantities. 
        $data = array(
           'rowid' => $item[$i], //this is line 241
           'qty'   => $qty[$i]
        );

        // Update the cart with the new information
        $this->cart->update($data);
    }

}
```

**view:**

```
<div id="main">
<?php if(!$this->cart->contents()):
    echo 'You don\'t have any items yet.';
else:
?>

<?php echo form_open('cart/update_cart'); ?>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:yellow;">Qty</td>
            <td style="background-color:yellow;">Item No/td>
            <td style="background-color:yellow;">Description</td>
            <td style="background-color:yellow;">Color</td>
            <td style="background-color:yellow;">Price</td>
            <td style="background-color:yellow;">Sub-Total</td>
            <td style="background-color:yellow;">Delete</td>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $i = 1; ?>
        <?php foreach($this->cart->contents() as $items): ?>

        <?php echo form_hidden('rowid[]', $items['rowid']); ?>
        <tr <?php if($i&1){ echo 'class="alt"'; }?>>
            <td>
                <?php echo form_input(array('name' => 'qty[]', 'value' => $items['qty'], 'maxlength' => '3', 'size' => '5')); ?>
            </td>
            <td><a style="font-size:11px;"><?php echo $items['id']?></a></td>
            <td><a style="font-size:11px;"><?php echo $items['name']; ?></a></td>
            <td><a style="font-size:11px;"><?php echo $items['warna']?></a></td>
            <td><a style="font-size:11px;">Rp. <?php echo number_format($items['price'],0,",",".");?></a></td>
            <td><a style="font-size:11px;">Rp. <?php echo number_format($items['subtotal'],0,",",".");?></a></td>
            <td><a href="<?= base_url();?>cart/delete/<?= $items['rowid'];?>"><img src="<?= base_url();?>assets/image/hapus.png"></img></a></td>
        </tr>

        <?php $i++; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"><strong>Total</strong></td>
            <td colspan="2"><a align="right"><?php echo $this->cart->format_number($this->cart->total()); ?></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p><?php echo "<input type='submit' class='Button' value='Update'>";?></p>
<?php 
echo form_close(); 
endif;
?>
```

edited the view, complete code.
when i click the update button it returned error live above.
thanks.

Comment: What value are you expecting to receive from `$this->input->post('rowid')`?

Comment: the rowid of the items

Comment: in what format? as an array? can you give an example of the value?

Comment: what is the value of `$item`?

Comment: Can you show us the generated markup? Maybe there is a not-closed tag BEFORE the view snippet you showed us...?

Comment: How does `$this->cart->total_items()` work?

Comment: it seems like it returns something like the total items i add to the cart. for example if i add 300 of quantity of an item it returns 300

Comment: But that reflects the number of items _before_ the form is posted, right?

Comment: tried to print_r($items) and i got this Array ( [rowid] => 0858ccdaef1d711a2eff18911cf79c51 [id] => 200508000100 [qty] => 300 [warna] => [price] => 35000.0000 [name] => BATTERY HI-TECH H-38 [subtotal] => 10500000 ) 1

Comment: The second listing is not so relevant to the error. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `$this->cart->total_items()` returns something different from the total items in the `$item` and `$qty` arrays. Later on, you are using this result to iterate these arrays, and the loop variable (`$i`) exceeds the arrays' boundaries.

Change your loop to:

```
for($i=0;$i < count($item);$i++)
```

You can choose `count($qty)` if you prefer, provided that the two arrays contain the same number of elements (which has to be true anyway, in order for the whole algorithm to work).

Comment: it works, thanks, but got another problems $this->cart->total_items() usually returns the items i have added but it returns the total quantity of the items i've added.

Comment: I don't quite follow. What is it supposed to return and what does it return instead? (and there's no _usually_, I guess its behavior is constant).

Answer (score -2):

when you receive the post you should use

rowid[] instead of rowid